# What would be the one-liner for an array with array of previous elements?

Tags: javascript

I have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

I need

```js
[
    [1],
    [1,2],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    ...
]
```

I imagine the result something like `const var = array.reduce **black magic**`

I tried something with reduce and a concat inside but I keep getting 'circular object Array'

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce((a,n,i) => (a.push([ ...(i ? a[i-1] : []), n]), a), [])`

Comment: @epascarello I don't understand why you did (a.push, a) on the return of the reduce, I never saw this syntax. The push return the length of the array, so on every loop you are returning `(0,accumulator),(1,accumulator), (2,accumulator) ... `

Comment: does not really need push either `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce((a,n,i) => ([...a, [ ...(i ? a[i-1] : []), n]]), [])`

Comment: With the push one, on every loop it returns the array with the comma operator.

Comment: that syntax still interest me, it's useful to use on returns, `return (a.push(x), a)` without creating a new variable, do you know the name of this syntax or some documentation to point me to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reduce is not always the answer. Sometimes there are better choices, e.g. `map` and `slice`:

```
 array.map((_, i) => array.slice(0, i + 1))
```

Comment: I guess I locked in the 'reduce will solve this'.  That's amazing. cheers